# gradle: compile C++ on Mac with ARM

Tags: c++, macos, gradle, arm

I am using:

- Gradle 7.2 with `cpp-library` plugin
- IBM Semeru JDK 11
- MacOS with M1 ARM (aarch64)
- gcc (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0)
- clang (Apple clang version 15.0.0, target: arm64-apple-darwin23.2.0)

I'm trying to compile [a fork of WALA](https://github.com/juliandolby/WALA/tree/java11) (using the gradle wrapper there, v7.2).

I get the error:

```
> Task :com.ibm.wala.cast:cast:compileDebugCpp FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':com.ibm.wala.cast:cast:compileDebugCpp'.
> Error while evaluating property 'compilerVersion' of task ':com.ibm.wala.cast:cast:compileDebugCpp'
   > No tool chain is available to build C++ for host operating system 'Mac OS X' architecture 'arm-v8':
       - Tool chain 'visualCpp' (Visual Studio):
           - Visual Studio is not available on this operating system.
       - Tool chain 'gcc' (GNU GCC):
           - Don't know how to build for host operating system 'Mac OS X' architecture 'arm-v8'.
       - Tool chain 'clang' (Clang):
           - Don't know how to build for host operating system 'Mac OS X' architecture 'arm-v8'.
```

I tried adding a `toolChains` section like this (in `com.ibm.wala.cast/build.gradle`):

```
model {
    toolChains {
       gcc(Gcc) {
          target("armv8-apple-darwin") // or aarch64-darwin or arm-linux-gnueabihf
          path("/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/gcc-13") // valid
       }
       clang(Clang) {
          target("armv8-apple-darwin")
          path("/usr/bin/clang")
       }
    }
}
```

but it fails with the same error (except the `visualCpp` part).

I also tried using more recent versions of gradle and JDK, but each failed with a different error.

How can I make this work? Or is it a known limitation of the used versions of gradle / cpp-library / the JDK?